# R: debug mode inside with() function

Tags: r, debugging, with-statement

For some reason, when the body of my function is inside a with() expression, the debug mode doesn't seem to let me step inside the with() part.  Why is that, and is there a way around this issue?  Below is a silly (but hopefully reproducible) demo.

```
    ff=function(x){
      print("Hello")
      with(iris,{
        y=x;
        z=y+mean(Sepal.Width);
        return(z);})
    }
```

Now enter debug mode and tryout the function...

```
    debugonce(ff);debugonce(with);
    ff(10)
```

Debug mode simply skips over the with() clause, and returns the answer (13.05733).  How do I step INTO those inner clauses?

Comment: It is debugging `with`, it's just that you only specified to debug the part that does the method dispatch. Try debugging `with.default`.

Answer (score 5):

This works, it's just that what you expect it to do is not what it does.  `debug` will look inside the `with` code, not inside the code you passed as an argument.  Look closely:

```
> ff(10)
debugging in: ff(10)
debug at #1: {
print("Hello")
with(iris, {
  y = x
  z = y + mean(Sepal.Width)
  return(z)
})
}
Browse[2]> n
debug at #2: print("Hello")
Browse[2]> n
[1] "Hello"
debug at #3: with(iris, {
y = x
z = y + mean(Sepal.Width)
return(z)
})
Browse[2]> n
```

Now look what's happening here, we are debugging in `with`:

```
debugging in: with(iris, {
  y = x
  z = y + mean(Sepal.Width)
  return(z)
})
```

And this is the key:

```
debug: UseMethod("with")
Browse[3]> n
[1] 13.05733
```

What happened?  Look at the `with` code:

```
> with
function (data, expr, ...) 
  UseMethod("with")
<bytecode: 0x00000000092f0e50>
<environment: namespace:base>
```

So as you can see, we did debug the single line in `with`.  You can also debug `with.default` if you want to see what's happening in `with` in more detail, but I doubt that will do what you want.  I don't know how to do that indirectly (even if you could debug `{`, which I don't think you can, that wouldn't help as you would be looking at the code for `{`, not the argument to `{`, same as with `with`), but as a hack you can use `browse()`:

```
ff=function(x){
  print("Hello")
  with(iris,{
    browser()    # <<<--- this will allow you to browse inside the expression
    y=x;
    z=y+mean(Sepal.Width);
    return(z);})
}
```